# Hide edit button pipeline last stage only in odoo 13 enterprise

Tags: odoo-13

How to hide edit button in only **CRM Won** stage using odoo 13 enterprise

Already I tried to use following code in odoo 13 **XML** view :

```
attrs="{edit:'false':[('stage_id','=','4')]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can Restrict the Edit Button by Extending the form view js.

Option 2:You can hide the Edit Buttons Conditionally using Record Rule. You need to set a domain in record rule.

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="your_reference_id">
    <field name="name">your reference name</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_model_name"/>
    <field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
    <field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
    <field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
    <field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(Condition)]</field>
</record>
```

Thanks

Comment: But i don't know the field name of edit button . "domain_force" is the edit button field name or any other field?

Comment: @Bala This one is the record rule which can be applied to record level. So if you added the domain_force which means is your condition is satisfied then this record will perform only apply the read access to the user. So they can not modify after that.[Beacuse you have only give them permission to read and create/write/unlink set to false].So this how the record rule perfrom in Odoo.

Comment: Ok I can understand .but i don't know how is it apply for odoo cloud online version.In record rule section asking "Rule Definition (Domain Filter)" ,access rights section already i unchecked apply for write,create,delete ..select "object" name is crm.lead then what is rule defintion for hide "edit" button in crm last stage only

Comment: @Bala Record Rule has to make the one XML file and there add my preference which I have added an answer. Where all the thing same only your model is crm.lead and domain force is like this  - [('stage_id','=','4')]

Comment: I tried this but i got the error                                                                                        
 "The requested operation ("read" on "Lead/Opportunity" (crm.lead)) was rejected because of the following rules:
- edit hide"

(Records: new (id=11), User: murugan.mu@gmail.com (id=2))

Answer (score 0):

You can also done by using **js**. Just replace your **module name** and **state**.

```
odoo.define('module.extension_name', function (require) {
var FormView = require('web.FormView');
FormView.include({
 load_record: function() {
  this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  if (this.model === 'your.model') {
      if (this.datarecord && (this.datarecord.state === 'state')) {
        this.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').css({'display':'none'});
      }
      else {
        this.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').css({'display':''});
      }
   }
});
```

});

Just call this **js** in in **xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="account assets"inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/path_to_js/static/src/js/file.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: "module.extension_name" means what ? In CRM module state means stage_id or 4?